# Configurable Installer for Windows

Tags: windows, installation

I wrote a Win32 app and it has an installer. The installer is signed with a certificate (the expensive kind). I want to give my customers the installer with configurations that are different for each customer. I want to set the configurations on demand and without resigning the installer, and yet to keep the installer signed in a valid way.

Is there a way to add such configurations to Win32 Installer (either Exe or MSI) without breaking the signature. I saw it was possible in the past to append information to the end of the file without invalidating the signature, but MS13-098 changed it.

If there is no such way, what would you recommend me to do? Prefer not to deliver more than one file, that takes no more than double click to install.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  You can use that certificate over-and-over again, signing any number of files or setup programs, it is not single-use.  Nor can you change an installer by appending bytes to the end of a file.  Just make your changes and resign it.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant, I can use the certificate as many times as I want, but only from my build machine that has the security dongle and only by by me using my very secret password. I want the configurations to be added by people who I trust, but not enough to share my dongle ;)

Comment: Also, sometimes the signing process takes a long time. For instance, when it should be approved by another company, not my case at the moment, but it could become my case in the future.

Comment: You are making a mountain out of a mole-hill, you couldn't stub your toe on it.  What you are proposing to do is just abject nonsense.  Gain some experience with this before you contemplate solving a non-existing problem.